# Unable to connect to Linux Server from Windows 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I am trying to connect shared folder which is in Linux server from Windows server 2008 Machine. Both machines are on my local network.

When i am able to connect the Linux machine from Windows XP or any other Computer, i am not able to understand the reason for not connecting from Windows 2008 Server.

Comment: Although it wasn't me who downvoted, I think your question needs more details. Lots of things could be at fault. Please state your Samba version (should be 3.5.x; otherwise, upgrade).

Comment: Does version really matters !! As i am able to connect to Linux Computer from Windows XP or any other Computer, why i am not able to connect it from Windows 2008 server ?

Comment: -1.  Please include information such as what UNC you are using to connect, if you're getting any errors.  Additional information about your network might also help.  Is it a single subnet, multiple subnets, firewalls?  Routers?

Comment: @Chok: of course Samba version is absolutely critical to determine whether your Windows system is able to connect or not. Improve your question and your attitude please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running an old version of Samba, it might not be compatible with Windows Server 2008. Server 2K8 includes a new version of the Windows file sharing technology ([SMB 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block#SMB2)) that, obviously, older versions of Samba may be incompatible with.

As a workaround, you may be able to [disable message signing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2.aspx) on the 2K8 server to permit the Linux box to talk to it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2008 has some firewall 'goodness'. Check your settings. Try to ping the linux box from the Windows box and make sure that these two can see each other. Please post your error messages, from the Windows box as well as the samba log errors from the linux box.